# Struct/Class metadata for object representation and managed/unmanaged interaction

Tags: c#, c++, memory

I know there is plenty of similar questions, but I want to understand very **specific** aspects that are never mentioned anywhere. In both cases: managed (NET runtime in this case) and native /unmanaged (c, cpp, etc)

Taken from here:
`https://adamsitnik.com/Value-Types-vs-Reference-Types`
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Qtnu.png]

[image]

The first issue that not just wasn't glossed over but not even **mentioned** is how your code/runtime supposed to know what type of struct you are dealing with? If struct is just all its data packed together, then where is metadata about what type of struct it is? Okay, may be in case of managed .NET runtime and binaries it is easier, it is part of the IL, but what about native binary code? It gets stripped 100%, if you open it for text reading there is no function or struct names in you binary. How would you know runtime what the struct you receive and how to treat/ parse it if there is no struct metadata with it? The pointer just points at memory, but there is no struct' structure and members there stored. At least class can be identified by extra data it has (object header and method table).

Things get even **more confusing** when you receive struct data from unmanaged/native space. You NEED to have that data embedded into struct otherwise how would you know what you receive?  And I *can't even begin to understand** how would this work for something like classes, because they are thousandfold more complex. How do you even return class from unmanaged space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If struct is just all its data packed together, then where is metadata about what type of struct it is?

There isn't any. With raw value data - whether that means an individual value, or an array/vector/whatever, the *consuming code* is the thing that knows how to interpret it. What it *is* is just: bytes.

> How would you know runtime what the struct you receive and how to treat/ parse it if there is no struct metadata with it?

Because it is defined in the API, either in a signature, or with human words such as "the pointer refers to the start of `len` elements of type `Foo`"

> You NEED to have that data embedded into struct

No you don't; you just need to agree *in advance* what you are sending/receiving. This is how the vast majority of interactions between different codebases works, and has always worked. *Having* object metadata is the **exception**, not the norm.

> How do you even return class from unmanaged space?

You wouldn't, if by "classes" in this context you mean managed objects.

Comment: Thanks Marc, can you expand a bit on `Because it is defined in the API, either in a signature`. What API/signature you are talking about in this case? I understand that IL for C#/.NET, for example, writes a lot of metadata inside assembly, but c/c++ stripped of all identifying data and compiled to machine code - where would it come from if not from struct data? What you are sayin is that struct is essentially sequence/array of raw memory bytes, and somehow the receiver knows how to read them. "if by "classes" in this context you mean managed objects." -- classes exist in c/c++ too on native

Comment: @Civ01 "classes exist in c/c++ too" it means something different, though; it isn't an interchangeable shared concept of "classes"; the RTTI/reflection in .NET is designed to be more informative. As for "where would it come from if not from struct data": from the code that was compiled in the first place. In C++ this is very literal, with it being part of the compilation; it is a *little* more nuanced in .NET assuming you don't do an AOT compilation, because the JIT loader needs to get involved between the IL and machine code, and the source assembly might differ between build and load.

Comment: Mainly, for C++ types, options compatibles with the Win32 API are assumes unless specified otherwise. If you compile C++ code with strange options you will either have to use attributes to specify the mapping or it might not works. In extreme cases, you would have to use mixed-mode C++ to make the bridge between managed and unmanaged types.C# do not parse C header file and as such, it is your responsability to ensure that the type you define on both sides have the exact same representation.